# How to Run IXP manager on localhost

Tags: php, laravel

I am working with IXp manager.

Here is the link of the overall code https://github.com/inex/IXP-Manager.

I want to add a few functionalities on the top of existing IXP.

I have installed the IXP manger using installation guide. But is there any other way or can anybody help with how to run the entire project on localhost (the project is developed using Laravel)?

Answer (score 0):

I have somehow figured the answer, I am posting here so it might be useful in future for someone.
First clone the IXP manager directory

```
git clone https://github.com/inex/IXP-Manager.git ixpmanager
cd ixpmanager
```

then spin the docker up using (you have to install the docker)

```
docker-compose -p ixpm up
```